# org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): Token has expired

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have an issue in spark streaming job. This job will do the below process.
   - Read the streaming data
   - Join the streaming data with Hive table (underlying data is present in HBase.

Program is running for 2-3 weeks but then it is failing with the below message.

```
19/04/27 05:56:16 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:ndc_common (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): Token has expired
19/04/27 05:56:16 WARN ipc.RpcClientImpl: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): Token has expired
```

Can someone please explain me how to resolve this issue. Though the cluster is kerborised.

Thanks

Comment: can you check paste contents of /etc/krb5.conf file ? From error it look like deligation token has been expired.

Comment: Hi @Shubhangi, thanks for the answer. Below is the output of krb5.log file. I see that the renew_lifetime is 7 days. So it will be failing for every 7 days. I have googled for this issue and found that we have to supply --keytab and --principal in spark-submit. Do we also have to provide jaas.conf file? We are using CDH distribuion.